# Updated Answer option for really old questions

Tags: feature-request

There is currently no way to flag an 'updated answer' after time goes on - so while the original answer might work for v1.1 of a product - 3 or 4 years later it may not be adequate anymore, but the question is landed on still from search engines for years.

It would be great if the community could flag an answer so that a newer updated answer becomes the top answer without discrediting the original solver.

Take this thread for example:
[How to align Datepicker to text box right edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060563/how-to-align-datepicker-to-text-box-right-edge/18993572#18993572)

Alex Barker provided the correct answer in Dec 2011. But the tool itself changed so that the correct  answer changed in 2013 (Bradley provided an update on Sept 24, 2013). Despite the fact the OP never selected an answer, Alex Barker did provide a correct answer, but it is outdated.

So two feature request: 1, an outdated button / flag for an answer and a replacement for the answer.

Comment: Generally, if there are enough differences between versions, it's worth having different questions entirely; if the questions specify a version then they aren't duplicates, conceptually.

Comment: These answers don't always need to be updated. Sometimes the question is about a *specific* version, and so updating the answer for a newer version would not be correct in that context.

Answer (score 4):

Voting continues on open questions forever, and over time certain answers can rise and fall (be up- and down-voted) depending on the technology. Many times I've googled for an answer for something, arrived at an SO question, and found the accepted or highest-voted answer just doesn't work for me, so I don't vote for it. If there are multiple answers, especially ones that say things along the lines of "*Version 1 worked the way @user1 says, but with the current Version 4 you should do it this way*", I'll vote them up. I may even leave a comment on @user1's answer saying "this doesn't work anymore, see @user2's answer for Version 4".

It's up to the OP to keep an eye on their questions and change the accepted answer as technologies change - I've seen it done many times, and not done many times more. Sometimes it's as simple as leaving a comment for the OP and asking them to reevaluate the answers (check their profile first to see if they're still an active user).

Overall, though, you just need to depend on the community to let the (currently) correct answers rise to the top. That's one of the reasons why voting is so important!

Comment: *"continues on open questions forever"*: closed Q's can also be voted.

Comment: @brasofilo that's true. I was thinking in contrast to locked questions, for example, which are kept for historical reasons but can no longer be voted/commented on or added to.

Answer (score -1):

### Executive Summary

What will flagging the answer accomplish?

1. If the user is inactive, the answer will continue to sit incorrect
2. If the user is active, a comment will give a notification just as much as a flag will

The only way to ensure the question is answered is to take action in to your own hands

### Inactive Users Can't Contribute

So what if Alex Barker hadn't logged in since 2012? You flag the answer. It remains unfixed. Now it has some label saying, "This isn't correct", but that doesn't help anyone since they came looking for an answer and there still isn't an answer. So flagging a question without contribution from the poster means:

1. The solution remains broken
2. The question remains unanswered
3. The reader still doesn't have a solution

### Active Users get Notified on Comment

If you comment on any answer, the owner of that answer gets a notification of the comment. So if the goal of flagging is to raise awareness of the person who made the answer, a comment will work just as well as a flag, and allows you to explain *why* the answer is outdated (what the error is, what version broke it, where the new documentation is, etc.). While the answer remains broken, at least anyone who stumbles across it and reads the comments will know where to start looking. But we still have a broken question.

### If You Want Something Done Right...

Let's say Alex Barker no longer uses [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) because he hates waffles, unicorns, and brown. Even if you comment, there is no guarantee that Alex will take his time to track down what has changed and fix it. And why should he? You've already figured out what the problem is, figured out that the answers available don't work, and you will do one of two things:

1. Post a separate question for the specific version
2. Figure it out yourself using the old outdated info and the latest documentation

If you post a separate question and get the answer, you can go back to the old answer and add a nice box at the top of the post saying:

> This answer works for versions 1.1 to 1.3. For version 1.4, please see [this answer](http://www.google.com)

Then anyone who comes looking for 1.1 to 1.3 can get their answer directly, and those looking for 1.4 can just click the link for enlightenment. Awesome.

If you figure it out yourself, you can either create a separate question and answer it yourself, or you can edit it directly in to Alex Barker's answer. You can just add headings:

> ### Versions 1.1 to 1.3
>
> *Insert Previous Answer Text Here*
>
> ### Version 1.4
>
> *Insert Own Answer Here*

People still get their answers, Alex gets a notification, and the world-wide web is made a better place.

Since you can fix it best yourself, creating an additional flag just adds extra noise and hurdles for users to get their answer. You are best equipped to solve the problem rather than an arbitrary flag nobody understands or knows how to act on!